# Database Connection Causes Python Program for Dialogflow to Crash

Tags: python, dialogflow-es

So I made a chatbot using Dialogflow. It's supposed to retrieve the number of daily covid-19 cases through webhook call. In my python program, I programmed so that it would save the fulfillment message to MongoDB and then send the message to Dialogflow. Only problem right now is that if I connect to my database, the program won't return anything. But when I don't connect, then it works just fine.

Here's the part of the code that I'm having trouble with:

```
log = Conversations.Log()
sessionID = req.get('responseId')
result = req.get("queryResult")
intent = result.get("intent").get('displayName')
query_text = result.get("queryText")
parameters = result.get("parameters")
cust_name = parameters.get("cust_name")
cust_contact = parameters.get("cust_contact")
cust_email = parameters.get("cust_email")
db = configureDataBase()

if intent == 'covid_searchcountry':
    cust_country = parameters.get("geo-country")
    if(cust_country=="United States"):
        cust_country = "USA"

    fulfillmentText, deaths_data, testsdone_data = makeAPIRequest(cust_country)
    webhookresponse = "***Covid Report*** \n\n" + " New cases :" + str(fulfillmentText.get('new')) + \
                      "\n" + " Active cases : " + str(
        fulfillmentText.get('active')) + "\n" + " Critical cases : " + str(fulfillmentText.get('critical')) + \
                      "\n" + " Recovered cases : " + str(
        fulfillmentText.get('recovered')) + "\n" + " Total cases : " + str(fulfillmentText.get('total')) + \
                      "\n" + " Total Deaths : " + str(deaths_data.get('total')) + "\n" + " New Deaths : " + str(
        deaths_data.get('new')) + \
                      "\n" + " Total Test Done : " + str(deaths_data.get('total')) + "\n\n*******END********* \n "
    print(webhookresponse)
    log.saveConversations(sessionID, cust_country, webhookresponse, intent, db)
    log.saveCases( "country", fulfillmentText, db)

    return {

        "fulfillmentMessages": [
            {
                "text": {
                    "text": [
                        webhookresponse
                    ]

                }
            },
            {
                "text": {
                    "text": [
                        "Do you want me to send the detailed report to your e-mail address? Type.. \n 1. Sure \n 2. Not now "
                        # "We have sent the detailed report of {} Covid-19 to your given mail address.Do you have any other Query?".format(cust_country)
                    ]

                }
            }
        ]
    }
```

Whenever I comment out **db=configureDataBase()**, everything works fine, but when I establish the connection again, the program will stop returning.

Here's the code for **configureDataBase()**:

```
def configureDataBase():
client = MongoClient("connection URL")
return client.get_database('Covid_19_DB')
```

If anyone can help me figure out why connecting to my database is causing it to break, I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: Since you mentioned the code works if you comment `db=configureDataBase()`, how do you access the database with the connection commented? Do you add any other line of code? Also, could you try to connect to the database as the first step of your code then execute/define the rest?

Comment: @AlexandreMoraes I don't. I have to use either one. I tried putting that line as the first code being executed for the function but still same results. Changing the position of the line does nothing in terms of fixing my issue

Comment: Could you explain in more details how do you retrieve the data if you comment this part `db=configureDataBase()`, since you mentioned it works when commenting it.

Comment: @AlexandreMoraes sure. So the connection to the database isn't for retrieving data, I only use it to store what the user asked and what the bot responded with. I have a separate function that actually retrieves the case data from Rapid API.
[Here](https://pastebin.com/yr0297xs) is the code for the functions, first one **makeAPIRequest()** checks the type of request, whether it's for world data or country, etc. Then the second one **makeApiRequestForCounrty()** gets the case data for country. I hope that helps you understand better mate how it works.

Comment: I have found a similar question to yours which might be helpful to look at for your case, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57608147/dialogflow-fulfillment-is-not-working-with-mongoose-to-connect-to-mongodb).

Comment: @AlexandreMoraes Thanks. I'll look into it and let you know.